# Unable to hide x axis for horizontal bar chart vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chart.js

I have to display a template with a horizontal bar chart without any axes.I'm using laravel 8 and Vuejs.
But no result until now. Any idea please ?
My code:
manager.blade.php

Inside the template tags:

```
 <tr v-for="arrMan in arrManagerList">                 
            <td>
                <div>
                    <strong>{{arrMan[0].first_name}} {{arrMan[0].last_name}}</strong>  
                </div>
            </td>  
            <td v-for="arr in arrMan"> 
                <div v-if="arr.count_finished_course != 0">                        
                    <div class="row">        
                        <bar-chart :options="options" :data="[['',arr.value_div]]" width="120px" 
                         height="70px"></bar-chart>
                        <div class="ml-4 mt-3" >
                            <strong>{{arr.count_finished_course}}/{{arr.count_assigned_course}} 
                           </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                   
            </td>                
        </tr>
```

Inside script tag

```
      data() {
        return {
            arrManagerList: [],
            coursesList: [],
            principalsList: [],
            courseAssignedList: [],
            courseFinishedList: [],
            managersDashboardList: []
        }
    },
    options: {           
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
              }
            }]
          },
    ......
   
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the options data is not at the right place in the script file.

It should be inside the data field.
Here is an example that generate this chart

[image]

```json
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    display: false // this will remove only the label
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }
        ],
        xAxes: [
            {
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Demo
Codepen
https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/952b318beaf06a0da8106960547d5eb5

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-vue-chartjs-ebrsk?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: But my problem is the data is not used only for the chart but for another part in the vue file, that's why there are many lists. ` data() {
            return {
                arrManagerList: [],
                coursesList: [],
                principalsList: [],
                courseAssignedList: [],
                courseFinishedList: [],
                managersDashboardList: []                
            }                    
        },`

Comment: Did you try the codepen link?
I have also added a codesandbox example which is more similar to your example.

Comment: I've tried codepen but no success, I'm going to try the codesandbox. Thanks!

Comment: my problem is that the barchart data is a result of a "for" inside another "for"